# MySQL Sort multiple timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 table in my database. They are admin action table and user action.
And have table structure as follows ::

Admin Action table

```
Action_id |  order    |   Action_type    |           timestamp          |   
   1          12            pending           2014-07-24 15:30:45
   2          12            packing           2014-08-24 14:12:11 
   3          12            shipping          2013-05-01 15:55:12
   4          12            packing           2011-11-25 21:10:22
```

User Action table

```
Action_id |  order    |   Action_type    |           timestamp          |   
   1          12            transfer           2014-07-22 15:30:45
   2          12            transfer           2014-09-23 14:12:11 
   3          12            transfer           2013-05-07 15:55:12
   4          12            transfer           2011-11-28 21:10:22
```

I want to sort timestamp both table. What is come before or after?
And Finally. There will be result as follows:

Activity table

```
Action_id     |   Action_type      |                 timestamp           |
    4               packing                    2011-11-25  21:10:22      //admin action 
    4               transfer                   2011-11-28  21:10:22      //user aciton
    3               shipping                   2013-05-01  15:55:12      //admin action
    3               transfer                   2013-05-07  15:55:12      //user aciton 
    1               transfer                   2014-07-22  15:30:45      //user aciton
    1               pending                    2014-07-24  15:30:40      //admin action
                       .....
```

**What is MySQL command** to slove this?

I know I can coding an algorithm in PHP for sort timestamp. But I think if good query from database. It helps to make it easy to handle in the next step.

Comment: what sql query have you tried?

Comment: `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`? But it's hard to see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This untested query should give you the expected result:

```
select * from (
Select * from `Admin Action`
union all
Select * from `User Action`) as a
order by timestamp
```